# Filtering word list by phrase in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

In R, I have unnested a chatlog into a data frame of words, as shown below.

[image: Text]

I use dplyr to filter by word to determine the count of each word e.g. `filter(word %in% word_pick)`

Is there a way to filter by a particular phrase, for example 'Hello world' I can search for 'Hello' and 'World' separately, but not together, as each word is a row.

Ideally I'd like a way to search for 'Hello' with 'world' in the next row of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can search patterns by `grepl` in dplyr syntax.

for example, you are looking for a row which includes "hello" whose next row  is "world"

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
filter(grepl('hello',your_colum) & grepl('world',lead(your_colum)))
```

Comment: I'm looking for rows which include 'hello' that are immediately followed by a row that includes 'world'.

Comment: @GregorHamill ok then, I updated the answer. please check it out.